# Hive failed write as class model. HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Color. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Tags: flutter

I am using a class model named AccountModle which contains Color,

I am getting an error of hive Writing regarding this data type..

How to create adapter for this data type..

[**ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Color. Did you forget to register an adapter?**

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class AccountModel extends HiveObject{
  @HiveField(0)
  String id;
  
  @HiveField(1)
  String name;
  
  @HiveField(2)
  DateTime createdOn;
  
  @HiveField(3)
  List<TransactionModel> transactions;
  
  @HiveField(4)
  bool isLocked;
  
  @HiveField(5)
  double payTotal;
  
  @HiveField(6)
  double receiveTotal;
  
  @HiveField(7)
  double balance;
  
  @HiveField(8)
  TransactionModel? lastEntry;
  
  @HiveField(9)
  Color color;

  
  AccountModel(
      {
        required this.id, required this.name,
        required this.transactions,
        this.isLocked=false,
        this.balance=0,
        required this.createdOn,
        this.lastEntry,
        this.payTotal=0,
        this.receiveTotal=0,
        this.color=Colors.red,

      });


}
```

But I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> ...Cannot write, unknown type: `Color`. Did you forget to register an adapter?

is clear:

Hive doesn't know how to store the `Color` objects because there's no adapter for it.

So, to register an adapter:

##### 1: Add the dependencies:

```
flutter pub add hive
flutter pub add hive_flutter
flutter pub add build_runner
flutter pub add hive_generator
```

##### 2: Preperae the object using `part`:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart'; 
part 'color.g.dart'; // <- Add this
```

##### 3: Create the `part` file:

Run:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

##### 4: Register the adapter:

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(ColorAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Color>('color');

  runApp(const MainApp());
}
```

##### See also

- the official docs on [generate an adapter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter)