# To register a specific type of data like songModel in Hive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, flutter-hive, just-audio

I have developed a music player using Flutter and I'm attempting to save a list of songs (SongModel) from the just_audio package into Hive. However, I'm encountering this error: "HiveError (HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: SongModel. Did you forget to register an adapter?)"
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Model:

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
 import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';
 part 'added_songs.g.dart';

 @HiveType(typeId: 3)
 class AddedSongs {
 @HiveField(4)
 List<SongModel> songs;

 AddedSongs(this.songs);
 }
```

Main class:

```
void main() async {
   await Hive.initFlutter();
   Hive.registerAdapter(AddedSongsAdapter());
   await Hive.openBox<AddedSongs>('AddedSongBox');
   runApp(const MyApp());
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive failed write as class model. HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Color. Did you forget to register an adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722086/hive-failed-write-as-class-model-hiveerror-cannot-write-unknown-type-color)

Comment: The question is similar but the answer is incorrect.